# Is it possible to fetch an input tag name that change everytime?

Tags: python, mechanize

i'm trying to fill in a form.
In this one, there is one input which it name changes everytime.

The html code

```
<input type="hidden" name="dr_value1" value="value2"/>
```

'dr' are the only thing that don't change.

Is it possible to fetch the value in this case ?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but show what you have written so far so people can help you.

Comment: everytime *what*?

Comment: everytime, the value1 and value2 change

Comment: Can you provide the url?